# How to check field coming from payload is not null and exist then convert to decimal?

Tags: apex

how could I check if "inboundQuote.totalPremiumAmt" is not null and exist then convert it to decimal and assign to quoteObj.Premium_Amount__c.

I have written this statment
`quoteObj.Premium_Amount__c = inboundQuote.totalPremiumAmt != null ? Decimal.valueof(inboundQuote.totalPremiumAmt) : null;`

*totalPremiumAmt of payload is mapped to Premium_Amount__c in Salesforce.

The problem is when there is totalPremiumAmt given in payload the Premium_Amount__c field is populating in Salesforce but there is a scenario when in payload totalPremiumAmt is not given in payload So the field value of Premium_Amount__c that was populated earlier is getting removed.

Once the value of Premium_Amount__c is populated it should not be removed no matter if in payload that field value is not there in payload.

Payload 1 where it has premium amount :-
{
"productName":"Habitational",
"status":"Premium",
"totalPremiumAmt":7.0524E+2,
"monthlyPremiumAmt":5.877E+1
}

Payload 2 where I am just changing the status :-
{
"productName":"Habitational",
"status":"Buy"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it to only assign when you have a value.

```
if (inboundQuote.totalPremiumAmt != null)
    quoteObj.Premium_Amount__c = Decimal.valueof(inboundQuote.totalPremiumAmt);
```

If you want it to never change once it's been set, you can add that condition also.

```
if (inboundQuote.totalPremiumAmt != null && quoteObj.Premium_Amount__c == null)
    quoteObj.Premium_Amount__c = Decimal.valueof(inboundQuote.totalPremiumAmt);
```